# Why does zsh allow to use combination of aliases in git without space?

Tags: git, zsh, alias

I have the following alias defined for both bash and zsh:

`alias g=git`

Additionally, in git I configured the git alias
`alias.st status`, so that I can get the git status with

`g st`.

Now I realized that in zsh, `gst` (without space) works as well. Any ideas as of how/why that happens?
In bash, the same command leads to `Command 'gst' not found`.

Comment: Are you by any chance using "oh-my-zsh" with the git plugin?

Comment: @Brian : Can't reproduce. What does `type gst` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used vanilla zsh in a long time and personally don't think that zsh by itself knows about the `gst` command unless you manually specify it. If you are using the popular framework [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/), it has a git plugin which defines some ~130 additional git aliases, some of which do include `gst`.

```sh
cat $HOME/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh | grep "gst"
alias gst='git status'
alias gsta='git stash save'
alias gstaa='git stash apply'
alias gstc='git stash clear'
alias gstd='git stash drop'
alias gstl='git stash list'
alias gstp='git stash pop'
alias gsts='git stash show --text'
```

If you have enabled this plugin from your `.zshrc`, then by default you have access to this alias as well (and the other 129).

Comment: Yikes. So many aliases that every possible typo has a defined command! :-) "Oops, I seem to have run the *start a nuclear war* command by typo..."

Comment: The solution is clear :) Just define a new alias which remaps the nuclear war cmd to `oisthrtsanwcbt`. Now we just need a new alias for copying the warhead codes automatically. And another one for the 2FA...